# Listas em PYTHON

Tags: python, lista

Eu estou usando listas para fazer um programinha. Inicialmente eu queria fazer um programa que criasse quantas variáveis a pessoa desejasse, porém eu acabei achando uma forma mais fácil. Pensei em criar uma lista e adicionar a ela 10 elementos. Após isso o programa teria de ler elemento por elemento para executar o próximo passo do programa(Não posso revelar o próximo passo), mas eu dei de cara com um problema, como fazer para que o programa leia as linhas separadas de uma lista? 
Por exemplo:

```
Lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

O meu programa iria pegar item por item, no caso, pegaria o item da lista L, o 1, e executaria o resto do programa, mais pra frente ele pegaria o item 2 e executaria, continuando até chegar no 5. Existe algum comando que me permita pegar o item da lista na posição que eu quiser e exibir na tela? Ou que permita ler linha por linha da lista? Como resolver meu problema? 
Já tentei de tudo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar o laço de repetição for.

Por exemplo.

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for item in lista:
    print(item) # item é o número contido na lista que vc quer usar.

    #Aqui vc coloca o resto do programa
```

Traduzindo:
Para cada item contido na lista:
    ele vai printar o (item)

ou vc pode fazer assim:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = len(lista)

for i in range(0, n):
    item = lista[i] # item é o número contido na lista que vc quer usar.
    print(item) 
    #Aqui vc coloca o resto do programa
```

É praticamente o mesmo do outro, mas de uma forma menos enxuta.

Answer (score 2):

Use `lista[0]` para pegar o primeiro elemento, `lista[1]` para pegar o segundo e assim por diante. Para saber o tamanho de uma lista use a função `len()`.

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(lista[0])
print(lista(1])
print(len(lista))
```

Outra coisa, em Python, evite criar variáveis com o primeiro caractere em maiúscula, ou seja, use `lista` ao invés de `Lista`. O uso da primeira letra em maiúsculas está reservado para a definição das classes (o Python não reclama mas pode gerar alguma confusão).

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar um loop for:

```
Lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(0,len(Lista)):
    print(Lista[i])
```