# Mudar valores de uma array usando for e if

Tags: python, array, loop

Olá, tenho uma array com diversos valores. Gostaria de substituir os valores acima de -0.54 para 1 e os abaixo de -0.54 para 0.

Segue abaixo minha array de nome resultados:

```
array([-2.06133692,  0.3721    , -1.35233125, -2.05725375,  0.39800875,
       -2.0544975 ,  0.66408308, -1.5466    ,  0.66212308, -2.559165  ,])
```

Tentei usar o seguinte código:

```
for x in resultados:
if x > -0.54:
    resultados = 1
else:
    resultados = 0
```

Mas o que eu recebo no final é o valor 0. Acredito que ele itera na array e só vai guardando de cada elemento, daí como o último é menor, guarda como 0 de resultado.

A dúvida pode parecer simples, mas estou a muito tempo travado nisso, e não sei como resolver. Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim como você falou, no seu código o `for` percorre cada elemento do array, atribuindo a cada loop um elemento do array à variável `resultado`. O problema é que ao utilizar o operador `=`, você não adiciona ou substitui um valor no array, na verdade o que você faz é substituir o array por um outro dado.

Assim sendo, como no último loop que o `for` dá o elemento é menor que -0.54, o valor atribuído à variável será zero. Se o seu objetivo é substituir cada valor do array por 1 ou 0, você deve utilizar colchetes depois do nome da variável (não sei qual linguagem você está usando, mas a maioria da linguagens utilizam colchetes para manipular elementos de arrays) passando o índice (posição) do elemento dentro dos colchetes, e aí sim, utilizar operador de atribuição.

Veja abaixo um exemplo do código escrito em Python (escolhi Python pois ele tem uma estrutura similar ao código da sua pergunta)

```
posicao = 0

for x in resultados:

    if x > -0.54:
        resultados[posicao] = 1
    else:
        resultados[posicao] = 0
    posicao += 1
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou! Estava com dificuldades nesse índice, acredito que agora não passarei mais por esse problema.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo o que entendi é isto:

Seu array esta assim:

```
array([-2.06133692,  0.3721    , -1.35233125, -2.05725375,  0.39800875,
       -2.0544975 ,  0.66408308, -1.5466    ,  0.66212308, -2.559165  ,])
```

Porém após o código, você deseja ele assim:

```
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

Correto?

Se sim, utilize este código:

```
array=([-2.06133692,  0.3721    , -1.35233125, -2.05725375,  0.39800875,
       -2.0544975 ,  0.66408308, -1.5466    ,  0.66212308, -2.559165  ,])

for j in range(len(array)):
    if array[j] > -0.54:
        array[j]=1 
    else:
        array[j]=0

print(array)
```

Pois para realizar a substituição desejada, você precisa informar o índice da [lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/287967/listas-em-python) para atribuir determinado valor.

Comment: Muito obrigado!